# Integrating factor O.D.E.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Having a bit of trouble with

$$dy/dx +3x^2y=x^2$$

What I can do is solve for $dy(x)/dx$ to find

$$dy(x)/dx = x^2-3x^2y(x)$$

Simplyfing

$$x^2(1-3y(x))$$

Dividing

$$\frac{dy(x)/dx}{(-3y(x)-1)} = x^2$$

Integrating both sides

$$\int{\frac{dy(x)/dx}{(-3y(x)-1)}dx}=\int{x^2dx}$$

yields

$$\frac{-1}{3}\ln|3y-1|+c_1 = \frac{1}{3}x^3+c_2$$

so we solve for $y(x)$

$$y(x)=\frac{-1}{3}e^{-x^3-3c_1}+\frac{1}{3}$$

or

$$y(x)=c_1e^{-x^3+\frac{1}{3}}$$

more simply

$$y(x) = c_1e^{x^{-3}}+\frac{1}{3}$$
But my confusion is the alternate technique of

$$dy/dx + P(x)y = Q(x)$$

where the integrating factor is

$$\mu(x)=e^{\int{P(x)dx + c}}$$

Which is my question,  how do I use the integrating factor more effectively? This alternate technique.

Comment: I suspect your first equation has a typo!

Comment: Perhaps someone could show the integrating factor technique? I know it involves $\mu$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the integrating factor method $P(x)=3x^2$ and therefore the integrating factor is $e^{x^3}$, multiplying both sides by this we get $e^{x^3}y'+3x^2e^{x^3}y=x^2e^{x^3}\implies \left(e^{x^3}y\right)'=x^2e^{x^3}$ integrating both sides we get $e^{x^3}y=\frac{1}{3}e^{x^3}+C$ finally, $\boxed{y=\frac{1}{3}+Ce^{-x^3}}$

Comment: LHS Integrating with respect to? RHS integrating with respect to??

Comment: @cryptomath both sides with respect to x

Comment: Thanks so much!